# Moving Nuendo Project

Tags: nuendo, omf, transfer, issue

Hi,

I had a students come in and try to dump a Nuendo 4 project on to the MACs in my department and all was well until he realized that all his automation was not included in the OMF.

Is there something that has to be done in order for him to transfer everything, automation included onto a drive and then to be able to dump it onto another computer and work with Nuendo from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need a little bit more info to form an opinion on this. Your saying he has an .omf that he imported into Nuendo? and the automation he did in his editing software did not transcribe?  If this is the case. There are some check boxes that need to be checked when importing said .omf,  I will say that I have found in Nuendo importing any .omf i cannot rely on the volume automation from the editor. I have always had stray points that can throw your mix off.

Comment: Yes, he is moving a Nuendo project to another MAC that has Nuendo on it. We could open his OMF but all the automation was missing. I have heard about this before and need to know if there is anything that I have to do which will allow the automation to be included with the OMF files. Thanks

Comment: you should check the boxes that say "include levels and pan" when you are exporting the .omf.

Answer (score 3):

OMF is not the way you want to go. You're going from Nuendo to Nuendo, so you can just move the project file (with all the files involved).

So for this, I recommend going: **File > Save Project To New Folder** then pick a folder you want to save to and what I do is choose: **Remove Unused Media**, which gets rid of files in your pool that aren't actually being used. This way you minimize the size of the project when moving it around. This is GREAT for archiving.

If you choose **Minimize Audio Files** then it will trim the audio to only what you are using.

By doing it this way, all your plugin automations and all that (assuming they are on both systems) will remain the same.

Hope this helps :-)